# SQL Server select query execution from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, select

```
string user = "1234";
string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From User where UserId = '{0}'",user);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

My `User` table consists of `UserId` and `Password` columns. The `UserId` column type is `nchar` and so I've used the single quotes. I get an error saying that

> *incorrect syntax near the keyword User"*

(I guess the table name `User` is being referred to here).

I have the connection string and other database environment related things correctly for I've checked the database connection status and it is open(during program execution).

What is the error in the syntax? I'm unable to retrieve the rows from my table.

Comment: Stick a break point on your SQLCommand line and grab the value of strSQL, then copy the string value and paste it into SSMS.  Execute and examine the query.  Without having the design of your table to hand its hard to diagnose what the syntax error would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`User` is a Keyword. Use square bracket around it to avoid the error. `Select * from [User]`

```
string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From [User] where UserId = '{0}'",user);
```

Also, you should always use parameterized query like below to prevent SQL Injection attack:

```
string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From [User] where UserId = @UserId");
```

Answer (score 8):

You should really use parameters for this:

```
string user = "1234";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [User] where UserId = @userid", cnn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", user);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // iterate your results here
    }
}
```

Well spotted by other posters, I never caught the reserved word thing with your table name.  I've amended my answer - but can't take credit for missing the obvious!

Answer (score 4):

you should wrap `user` with brackets `[]`

```
string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From [User] where UserId = '{0}'",user);
```

The query above is vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. It should be parameterized to avoid this. The following is an example:

```
string user = "1234";
string strSQL = "Select * From [User] where UserId = @userID";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
myCommand.AddWithValue("@userID", user);
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

use the following

- `Try-Catch` block for proper catching of errors
- `using` statement for proper object disposal

snippet:

```
string user = "1234";
string strSQL = "Select * From [User] where UserId = @userID";
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", user);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["columnName"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've got some errors in the code. "myCimmand" is misspelled, and it looks like you used parenthesis when you should have used brackets, perhaps? I'm not exactly sure what you did on line 4?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap with `[]`. It is a keyword. Read [`Reserved Keywords`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) article from MSDN.

```
string strSQL = string.Format("Select * From [User] where UserId = '{0}'",user);
```

But more important part, your query is open for an [`SQL Injection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) attack. You should always use parameterized queries.

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [User] where UserId = @userID";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", user);
```